# cell.backgroundColor question

Tags: ios, cell, tableview

I found this handy code on the internet,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 cell.backgroundColor = (indexPath.row%2)?[UIColor grayColor]:[UIColor clearColor];
 }
```

I know that it makes every row a gray, then clear, then gray sort of pattern. But I want to switch off between a ***light gray and a dark gray***. How can I modify the above code so I can switch between those two colors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both `darkGrayColor` and `lightGrayColor` are valid color names, so change it to the code below. All I did was change your color names.

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = (indexPath.row%2)
        ? [UIColor lightGrayColor]
        : [UIColor darkGrayColor];
}
```

**Explanation of how the alternating row colors work**: The `indexPath.row % 2` performs a modulus on the index: if it has no remainder when divided by two, the color will be `lightGrayColor`; otherwise, it will be `darkGrayColor`. I have spaced out the code a little to make it more obvious what is happening.

Comment: Oh, I thought UIColor just had plain color names and no light/dark ones too, thanks for the info and answer. I will accept the answer in 6 mins

Comment: I just tested it with that code and it looks pretty awful, those colors aren't great. Is there a way for me to customize the color via IB?

Comment: @iBrad: Yes you can change the gray colors. Use this function `CGContextSetGrayFillColor (CGContextRef c, CGFloat gray, CGFloat alpha);` to compose what ever tone of gray you like.

Comment: I would recommend (indexPath.row & 1). Same result as (indexPath.row % 2), just without the modulus calculation.

Comment: @Fostah, why would your approach `(indexPath.row & 1)` be better? And what exactly is a modulus calculation? Thanks.

Comment: @JFS The % is the modulo operator that performs the modulus calculation, which can be a heavy calculation. "& 1" is just a bitwise operation that'll be sure to be fast.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example on how to alternate cells background colors made by apple: It's called [AdvancedTableViewCells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedTableViewCells/Introduction/Intro.html) and is actually the tableview cell used in the App Store.

In the example they are alternating two different Images as backgroundViews of the cells by passing a flag to the cell.

```
self.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage] autorelease];
```

If you have trouble understanding the example let me know...

Comment: Hey do you know of any good images I can use of different gray colors, because I am using the code from the other answerer and it looks pretty bad. I just want to make the UI look nice..